# How can I use padding-inline-start with document.getElementById()?

Tags: javascript, css, function, getelementbyid, queryselector

Can someone help me how to write the 2 lines correctly in this function:

```
  function Arabic_fun() {
            document.getElementsById("#navleft").style.padding - inline - start = "0px";
            document.getElementsById("#navleft li ul").style.padding - inline - start = "0px";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues:

1. No such function `getElementsById`. Did you mean `getElementById`?
2. `getElementById` does not need a `#` in the parameter
3. `#navleft li ul` is not a valid id. If you want nested selectors like in CSS, use `querySelector` (single) or `querySelectorAll` (multiple elements)
4. `padding - inline - start` should be `paddingInlineStart`

```
function Arabic_fun() {
  document.getElementById("navleft").style.paddingInlineStart = "0px";
  document.querySelector("#navleft li ul").style.paddingInlineStart = "0px";
}
```